# Can I load a VMWare VM created using Fusion on VMWare Player?

Tags: mac, vmware-workstation, vmware-fusion

My primary workstation (at home) is a Mac and I am running Ubuntu on Fusion 2. Can I copy that VM onto a disk/USB flash drive and load it on a Windows machine running VMWare Player?

Comment: What happened when you tried? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the versions are compatible. Make sure you have the latest VMware Player and know that not all the features of your Fusion machine will not work. Other than that, I do it all the time.

Comment: could you be more specific about which features will not work?

Comment: The automatic drive mapping and printer sharing doesn't work out of the box. You will also run into Unity issues from what I have found.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an XP in Fusion, which now runs under vmware player under Ubuntu 9.04.  It works well.

I found it hard to create new shared folders, and the player does not support snapshots.  Other than that I have been very pleased - even Ctrl-Alt-Del works as expected.  Note, Fusion creates a lot of helper files to allow OS X to know that the VM can handle a given file type.  Those files are not needed and may delay copying a lot.